# How to Fix Rails Error: Development database is not configured - ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have been been repeatedly getting this error despite trying to change many things.

I viewed other SO pages and changed indentation, names, etc. Really not sure what's going on. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
# SQLite version 3.x
# gem install sqlite3
#
# Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
# gem 'sqlite3'
#
 default: &default
 adapter: postgresql
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000

 development:
 <<: *default
 database: lightpath_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
<<: *default
database: lightpath_test

production:
<<: *default
database: lightpath_production
```

Comment: Have you tried using sqlite3 as a development database? Looks like you're trying to use postgres and it isn't configured/running properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching back to the default `database.yml` file.

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

You're likely getting that error because you're trying to use Postgres database without properly configuring Postgres on your development machine/server.

For details on how to switch over to postgres you should watch [this RailsCast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql).